# Jaybird CallableStatement not executed until getting output parameter

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, callable-statement, jaybird

I have this `Java` code:

```
Connection conn = connectionProvider.getConnection();
statement = conn.prepareCall("execute procedure rm_set_coordinates(?,?,?)");
statement.setInt(1, userId);
statement.setString(2, String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
statement.setString(3, String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
statement.execute();
```

Where `rm_set_coordinates` is `Firebird` stored procedure:

```
create or alter procedure RM_SET_COORDINATES (
    PCAR_LOGIN integer,
    PLAT varchar(20) = 0,
    PLNG varchar(20) = 0)
returns (
    ORESULT integer,
    ORESULT_MSG varchar(500))
as
begin
     update ref_car rc  set rc.rm_last_connect_time='now',rc.rm_lat=:plat,rc.rm_lng=:PLNG  where rc.id=:pcar_login;
     oresult=1;
     oresult_msg='';
  suspend;
end
```

When I execute this code data in `ref_car` table is not changing.
But if I'll add this line to above code:

```
statement.getInt(1);
```

which returns value of `oresult` output parameter then it's ok, data in `ref_car` table is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your use of `SUSPEND` in the stored procedure. The keyword `SUSPEND` is intended for selectable stored procedures (stored procedures that produce multiple rows of data). As your stored procedure only produces a single row, the `SUSPEND` is unnecessary (and the cause).

For a selectable procedure, Jaybird transforms your `execute procedure rm_set_coordinates(?,?,?)` to `SELECT * FROM rm_set_coordinates(?,?,?)`. I am not 100% sure about the implementation details of Firebird stored procedures, but it looks like a block containing a `SUSPEND` is either only executed when a row is actually fetched, or all changes upto the previous `SUSPEND` are reverted when the row is not fetched before the statement is closed or reused.

The end result is however: no rows fetched, no changes. When executing a selectable stored procedure (ie: it contains a `SUSPEND`), Jaybird retrieves results in a different way than when it is a 'normal' executable stored procedure .

An executable stored procedure is known to have only one row (or no rows) of results, so those values are retrieved immediately on execute, and the result can be retrieved using the `getXXX()` methods. For a selectable stored procedure the results are retrieved like a normal `ResultSet`. Normally for a selectable stored procedure you should use `executeQuery()` and process the `ResultSet` returned. Due to an implementation artefact and compatibility with older versions of Firebird (where it was not possible to differentiate between selectable and executable procedures), it is possible to retrieve values of the first (or current) row of the `ResultSet` using the `getXXX()` methods of the `CallableStatement` as well.

**TL;DR**: Remove the `SUSPEND`.

**Disclosure**: I am one of the developers of Jaybird